# Error While saving quote programmatically

Tags: magento-1.9, sales-quote

> Notice: Array to string conversion  in
>   D:\Projects\magento\lib\Varien\Db\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql.php on line 3074

Comment: You are trying to save an array into Mysql which isn't possible.  MySQL error reporting should give you the code stack it was trying to save and help you find out exactly what is wrong

Comment: I am programmatically creating order but while saving quote this error occurs, the reference tutorial link 
https://webkul.com/blog/programmatically-create-order-magento/

Comment: Have you tried changing street from an array to a standard input for testing?

Comment: You can also look in the MYSQL error log or turn on php error reporting (method 3 or 4 here) http://blog.chapagain.com.np/magento-1-x-enabling-viewing-full-error-display/

Comment: show your code here